# How do I represent these measures (bends and prebends) in GuitarPro?

Tags: notation, electric-guitar, sheet-music, software, tablature

I was reading through a book when I came across this lick. I tried to represent it in guitar pro but am finding difficulty. Can you please help me with this lick?
I understand that these are grace notes but I am not able to add effects to the grace notes like prebend and release. Is there something that I am missing? [image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [bend tool](https://static.guitar-pro.com/gp7/manual/GuitarPro7-user-guide.pdf) (p95) for this kind of things. It will allow you to add prebends and release part on a bend.

There is also a "prebend-release" which should match pretty well what you want to do.

Hope it helps,

Comment: I checked the manual but details about adding bends, prebends and release to a grace note is not given. In the second note in the first bar, G is a gracenote. There's a prebend and release applied to this note and F (10th fret 3rd string) is played.
The problem I am facing is with this specific point wherein I am not able to add any features to the grace note

Comment: @adhithyaravichandran Are you sure these grace notes have a real utility except giving the starting point of the bend? Score says G but tab says 12+FB which is A. I would personally remove these grace notes and use the bend capabilities of guitar pro